# Creating a dwf/rvt/obj file from java

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

Let say i have to model real room, with some furniture (represented as parallelograms - as simple as is possible).

I know that position of that furniture will change and it will be needed to update project.

I`m wonder is there any possible to create that model using java (or some other) language (maybe by some autodesk API) and save it as DWF or RVT file. Later this object will be used in browser Viewer. Information I will need to save are coordinates of room, furniture, and some properties information that could be read in viewer site.

I know that it should be updated in appropriate tool but i want to automatize process of room modification, because i will know coordinates of new position of that furniture and then i wish to just do it by code.

So is possibility to create 3d model and save it to DWF/RVT file from code?

Answer (score 0):

We are working on [Design Automation API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/overview/) for Revit which will allow you to pilot Revit API from the Cloud, so anything you can achieve in Revit through API will be doable. Unfortunately at the moment Design Automation is only available for AutoCAD, so you can create .dwg and .dxf but not yet .rvt or .dwf.

Comment: So you are saying that i should create 3d model by AutoCAD. I found that it could be possible by using .NET, i`m right?
In next step i could transform .dwg file to .dwf to present it in viewer?

Comment: acording to https://www.autodesk.com/viewers/all-viewers i dont have to convert anything, i just need to create 3d object using some API, it could be done (with adding object properties) by using that .NET API?